# Kubernetes pod failed to connect to external service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

[image]

I have an **Azure Kubernetes Cluster** Running with **Azure CNI (virtual network)** as the Network. The cluster is running on 1 subnet of the network.

On another subnet, I have a **Virtual Machine** running as it has a private IP of `10.1.0.4`.

Now I have a pod in the K8S cluster, which is trying to connect with the Virtual Machine. But it's not able to do so.

Also, the `ping 10.1.0.4` from inside the pod gives a timeout.

Please help me to figure out, what I am doing wrong so that I can `connect the Pod with the VM`.

Comment: do you have any NSGs configured on your subnets?

Comment: Please disable firewall for VM and then try.

Comment: You required internal load balacer between VM and AKS for communication,Check out this link it may help you : https://fabriciosanchez-en.azurewebsites.net/implementing-virtual-machine-to-pod-communication-in-azure-kubernetes-service-aks/

Comment: Hi @ArkadipBhattacharya, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 0):

•   `You cannot directly create communication between an AKS cluster pod and a Virtual Machine as the IP assigned to a pod/node in an AKS cluster is a subset range of the address space of the higher CIDR IP address range assigned while deploying the cluster`. And communication within the cluster between the nodes is uninterrupted and possible readily. But the same with resources other AKS is **restricted as they are governed by Azure CNI framework policy which directs the Kubernetes cluster to direct traffic outbound of the cluster in a regulated and conditional way**.

•   Thus, the above said can only be achieved by **initiating intermediate services such as an internal load balancer between the AKS and the VMs as the CIDR of the VM and the AKS is different**. So, `leveraging the Azure plugin to deploy an internal load balancer as a service through AKS` is only way through which you can achieve communication between AKS pod and a VM deployed in Azure. Below is a diagram for illustration purposes.

[image: AKS with ILB]

To deploy the **internal load balancer through YAML files in AKS** for external communication with VMs, kindly refer to the link below for details: -

https://fabriciosanchez-en.azurewebsites.net/implementing-virtual-machine-to-pod-communication-in-azure-kubernetes-service-aks/